# Spherical Bessel Zeros

Tags: special-functions, roots

I was wondering if there is a known closed form solution for the zeros of the spherical Bessel functions.  While doing a quantum assignment, I came across them as a solution for the spherical infinite potential well.  However, I only read about them as just a sequence of numbers, but no generating function or closed form expression.  Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you already had a look at Watson's *Treatise* (cfr. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98885/classical-texts-that-should-not-be-missing-from-any-shelf/99101#99101)?

Comment: @Pacciu Thanks, I just picked up a copy, and made a list of some books from that thread ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n=-1,0$, finding the roots of the spherical Bessel functions $j_n(x)$ and $y_n(x)$ is somewhat easy, since:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
j_{-1}(x)&=&\frac{\cos\,x}{x}&\quad&y_{-1}(x)&=&\mathrm{sinc}(x)\\
j_0(x)&=&\mathrm{sinc}(x)&\quad&y_0(x)&=&-\frac{\cos\,x}{x}\\
\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm{sinc}(x)=\dfrac{\sin\,x}{x}$ is the sine cardinal. Solving for zeros of other orders results in rather complicated transcendental equations, which I doubt have closed-form solutions. However, you will want to see these [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21) [entries](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.58) for some more information that can help you in numerically determining the zeros (e.g., asymptotic expansions); approximations derived from formulae there can then be subsequently polished with Newton-Raphson or some other iterative method of choice.

Answer (score 0):

## Cheat Code: spherical Bessel roots *are* their respective half-integer Bessel roots

According to [Abramowitz, 1964, Ch9, pp 440,"Zeros and Their Asymptotic Expansions"](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_440.htm)

> The zeros of $j_{n}(x)$ and $y_{n}(x)$ [i.e.: Spherical Bessel] are the same as $J_{n+1/2}(x)$ and $N_{n+1/2}(x) $ [i.e.: 'Normal' Bessel]

## *Mathematica* Implementation

I used, for the spherical Bessel of the first kind:

```
nRoots = 4;
nBessel = 3;
SphBesselRoot[l_, k_] := N[BesselJZero[l + 1/2, k]];
Grid[Table[SphBesselRoot[l, i], {l, 0, nBessel}, {i, 1, nRoots}]]
```

This prints a table of the first four roots (columns) for the four spherical Bessel functions (rows) :

```
3.14159 6.28319 9.42478 12.5664
4.49341 7.72525 10.9041 14.0662
5.76346 9.09501 12.3229 15.5146
6.98793 10.4171 13.698  16.9236
```

Comparing to [tables of the roots online](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node81.html#11777), this table is in good agreement.

I found this method easier than root finding or asymptotic expressions.

Comment: ...and how exactly did you think were these computed internally by *Mathematica*, by the swish of a unicorn's tail?

Comment: Nope, I didn't have enough money to add unicorns to my computer! I posted this because I could find lots of tables, but few generating functions / ways to compute the tables easily and quickly.